# Can I check-in for both flights in Bangkok, if not do I need a transit visa or Sydney?

Tags: visas, transit, international-travel, australia, italian-citizens

I'm traveling from Bangkok to Auckland, changing flights in Sydney, the stop over is 5h and 10m and the flights are both with Qantas. I hold an Italian passport.

- Do I need a transit visa?
- Is it possible to check-in for both flights in Bangkok, if not and I have to exit